# PG rails db:create InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, pg, manjaro

I executed:

```
$ GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db1 to user1
$ ALTER USER user1 CREATEDB
$ ALTER USER user1 CREATEDB
$ ALTER USER user1 WITH 'pass'
```

But still get an error on

```
$ rails db:create
```

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: pg_app_development
```

Linux Manjaro.
Rails 6.0.2.2
Ruby 2.7.1
Pg 12.2

Also I do not want to put superuser info in database.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ALTER USER USER1 WITH CREATEDB
```